# Springboot control BOOT-INF/lib classloading order

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

`SpringBoot version 2.3.1`
Is there a way to control the classloading order of binaries inside BOOT-INF/lib. Whether in any way
`BOOT-INF/classpath.idx` can be used for this. The file is currently generated while building the fat jar but how do we manipulate the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the jar files in `BOOT-INF/lib` comes from the build system that you’re using. Judging by the question’s tags, you’re using Maven.

In Maven, the ordering is influenced by the order in which you have declared the dependencies in your `pom.xml` file. The nearer the top of the `<dependencies>` that a `<dependency>` is declared, the earlier it will appear on the classpath.

While changing the order of your dependencies gives you control over the order of the classpath, I would caution against relying upon it. It can cause things to be quite brittle and can lead to subtle and hard-to-track-down bugs. If possible, I would try to clean up your application’s classpath so that its ordering does not matter instead.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Whether the ```BOOT-INF/classpath.idx``` is used only under ```JarLauncher``` or is it applicable for ```PropertiesLauncher``` as well.

Comment: Can maven dependency control the order of lib in classpath ?

Comment: How about gradle?

Comment: @NanoNova I believe it's essentially the same with Gradle. Changing the order of the entries in your `dependencies` block will change the order of the classpath.

Comment: Hi @Andy, thanks for your answer. I've checked and you are right. But this only happened if using `java -cp`. 
My situation is my springboot app trying to find log4j2.xml in other jars. With `java -cp`, the classloader pick the one which defined in gradle ealier. With `java -jar` to boot my app, it turns to chooos another one, and always another no matter what order of dependencies defined in gradle.

Comment: How is the `java -cp` command being created? If you're doing it, you are defining the order of the classpath and Gradle isn't involved. I think you should ask a separate question as comments on an answer about Maven aren't a good place for a Gradle-specific problem.